# Service to convert crypto to fiat and Withdraw

Tags: service

I'm wondering if there's any service which I can use to convert crypto to fiat and make a withdrawal, e.g. someone puts USDT in a wallet that I create and automatically I convert it to USD and make a withdrawal to a bank account X, something like BinanceUS or Coinbase that you can do the Withdraw in USD.

[Edited]

I think I didn’t explain myself well, what I mean is, for example, you as a client want to pay a business with cryptocurrency but said business doesn’t accept that type of payments, so I as an intermediary accept the payment in cryptocurrency, I convert it to USD and I pay the merchant in USD, that is, it’s not for me personally to make the withdrawal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binance provides such services through their withdrawal service. You can access it by going to **wallet > fiat and spot > withdraw**. Read more about it [here](https://binancewiki.com/how-to-withdraw-crypto-and-fiat-currency-on-binance-051310). You can put your funds to a Binance wallet and withdraw. This can be used to withdraw the money to a  business’s bank account and the process could be automated with the [withdrawal api](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#withdraw-sapi) of Binance.

There are also crypto exchange offices all over the world. You can search if there are crypto exchanges near by and pull of your transaction there. Note that these exchanges usually take commission which could be large but it varies from place to place.

An alternative way would be to use crypto ATMs which let you to convert your crypto to fiat in place. You can check for near by ATMs using https://coinatmradar.com/.

Comment: I think I didn’t explain myself well, what I mean is, for example, you as a client want to pay a business with cryptocurrency but said business doesn’t accept that type of payments, so I as an intermediary accept the payment in cryptocurrency, I convert it to USD and I pay the merchant in USD, that is, it’s not for me personally to make the withdrawal

Comment: @WanerA.PeñaSánchez you can use the fiat withdrawal service to withdraw the money to that businesses bank account. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: if it can be automatically yes, it would help me, I’ll investigate if it’s possible, thanks.

Comment: @WanerA.PeñaSánchez the binance has a withdrawal API  https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#withdraw-sapi. This could help you to automate the process. Also I eddited the answer to contain this information.

Comment: thanks man for your help